# Sharing Gatsby Site on Mobile Safari Produces {:ROOT_URL}undefined/

Tags: gatsby, mobile-safari

When attempting to share the link to a Gatsby site from mobile safari, the resulting link has "undefined/" appended to the end of it. This only happens at the site root, not on any other pages.

Has anyone else experienced this, and do you have any insight about how to solve it?

I navigated to my site's root in mobile safari, and hit the "share" button. I would have expected it to share the site URL, but instead it shared the site URL + "undefined/".